# Selenium download chromedriver for any os

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to the selenium, trying to build a project now I want to download chromedriver at the start of the program irrespective of the OS. I found a working code online written by [primaryobjects](https://gist.github.com/primaryobjects),
the code seems to work it is indeed downloading appropriate chromedriver, but even after downloading it is again doing the same time. I think the while loop is infinite but I can not resolve it.
I tried [chromedriver-autoinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-autoinstaller/), and it worked but really do not want to install anything extra for this simple work.
Would appriciate a little help.Suggestions are appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException, SessionNotCreatedException
import sys
import os
import pathlib
import urllib.request
import re
import zipfile
import stat
from sys import platform

def get_driver():
    # Attempt to open the Selenium chromedriver. If it fails, download the latest chromedriver.
    driver = None
    retry = True

    while retry:
        retry = False
        is_download = False

        try:
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.add_argument('--headless')
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='./chromedriver')
        except SessionNotCreatedException as e:
            if 'This version of ChromeDriver' in e.msg:
                is_download = True
        except WebDriverException as e:
            if "wrong permissions" in e.msg:
                st = os.stat('./chromedriver')
                os.chmod('./chromedriver', st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)
                retry = True
            elif "chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH" in e.msg:
                is_download = True

        retry = is_download and download_driver()

    return driver

def download_driver():
    # Find the latest chromedriver, download, unzip, set permissions to executable.
    result = False
    url = 'https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads'
    base_driver_url = 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/'
    file_name = 'chromedriver_' + get_platform_filename()
    driver_file_name = 'chromedriver' + '.exe' if platform == "win32" else ''
    pattern = 'https://.*?path=(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'

    # Download latest chromedriver.
    print('Finding latest chromedriver..')
    opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener({})
    stream = opener.open(url)
    content = stream.read().decode('utf8')

    # Parse the latest version.
    match = re.search(pattern, content)
    if match and match.groups():
        # Url of download html page.
        url = match.group(0)
        # Version of latest driver.
        version = match.group(1)
        driver_url = base_driver_url + version + '/' + file_name

        # Download the file.
        print('Version ' + version)
        print('Downloading ' + driver_url)
        app_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        chromedriver_path = app_path + '/' + driver_file_name
        file_path = app_path + '/' + file_name
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(driver_url, file_path)

        # Unzip the file.
        print('Unzipping ' + file_path)
        with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
            zip_ref.extractall(app_path)

        print('Setting executable permission on ' + chromedriver_path)
        st = os.stat(chromedriver_path)
        os.chmod(chromedriver_path, st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)

        # Cleanup.
        os.remove(file_path)

        result = True

    return result

def get_platform_filename():
    filename = ''

    is_64bits = sys.maxsize > 2**32

    if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
        # linux
        filename += 'linux'
        filename += '64' if is_64bits else '32'
    elif platform == "darwin":
        # OS X
        filename += 'mac64'
    elif platform == "win32":
        # Windows...
        filename += 'win32'

    filename += '.zip'

    return filename
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for but you could try installing [chromedrivermanager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) import it like this `from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager` and use `driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code a little bit, now it's working almost fine. except it downloads every time you run the code. but it get's the job done.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException, SessionNotCreatedException
import sys
import os
import pathlib
import urllib.request
import re
import zipfile
import stat
from sys import platform

def get_driver():
    # Attempt to open the Selenium chromedriver. If it fails, download the latest chromedriver.
    driver = None
    retry = False

    while not retry :
        retry = False
        is_download = False

        try:
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.add_argument('--headless')
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='./chromedriver')
        except SessionNotCreatedException as e:
            if 'This version of ChromeDriver' in e.msg:
                is_download = True
             
        except WebDriverException as e:
            if "wrong permissions" in e.msg:
                st = os.stat('./chromedriver')
                os.chmod('./chromedriver', st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)
                retry = True
                
            elif "chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH" in e.msg:
                is_download = True
                
        retry = is_download and download_driver()
    
    return driver

def download_driver():
    # Find the latest chromedriver, download, unzip, set permissions to executable.
    result = False
    url = 'https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads'
    base_driver_url = 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/'
    file_name = 'chromedriver_' + get_platform_filename()
    driver_file_name = 'chromedriver' + '.exe' if platform == "win32" else ''
    pattern = 'https://.*?path=(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'

    # Download latest chromedriver.
    print('Finding latest chromedriver..')
    opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener({})
    stream = opener.open(url)
    content = stream.read().decode('utf8')

    # Parse the latest version.
    match = re.search(pattern, content)
    if match and match.groups():
        # Url of download html page.
        url = match.group(0)
        # Version of latest driver.
        version = match.group(1)
        driver_url = base_driver_url + version + '/' + file_name

        # Download the file.
        print('Version ' + version)
        print('Downloading ' + driver_url)
        app_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        chromedriver_path = app_path + '/' + driver_file_name
        file_path = app_path + '/' + file_name
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(driver_url, file_path)

        # Unzip the file.
        print('Unzipping ' + file_path)
        with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
            zip_ref.extractall(app_path)

        print('Setting executable permission on ' + chromedriver_path)
        st = os.stat(chromedriver_path)
        os.chmod(chromedriver_path, st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)

        # Cleanup.
        os.remove(file_path)

        result = True

    return result

def get_platform_filename():
    filename = ''

    is_64bits = sys.maxsize > 2**32

    if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
        # linux
        filename += 'linux'
        filename += '64' if is_64bits else '32'
    elif platform == "darwin":
        # OS X
        filename += 'mac64'
    elif platform == "win32":
        # Windows...
        filename += 'win32'

    filename += '.zip'

    return filename
```

Answer (score -1):

When

```
is_download = True
```

then you use `break` method.

Comment: HI,
thanks for the response. can you specify at which line you added the break statement?

Comment: @KUNALDAS I think they are suggesting you to add `break` after wherever you have `is_download = True` in the code.

Comment: @SiddharthDushantha, tried the same, did not work

Comment: Please don't ask for votes in your answers. People will upvote if they find your answer helpful (and downvote for the opposite...)